# bash script to filter lines of data

Tags: bash

my bash script :

```
awk '
    /^+/ {
        if (NR % 2 == 1) {
            for (i = 2; i <= NF; i += 2) {
                printf "%s\t%s\n", $i, $(i+1)
            }
        } else {
            for (i = 2; i <= NF; i += 2) {
                printf "%s\t%s\n", $i, $(i+1)
            }
        }
    }
' nportModel.sp.isrc > output_file.txt
```

the **nportModel.sp.isrc** file cantain data "sample"

```
IVDD_VDD_0_000 VDD_VDD_0 VSSA0_VSSA0_5 PWL 
+ 0.00000e+00 1.87110e+00 2.00000e-11 1.09317e+01 4.00000e-11
+ 1.02981e+01 6.00000e-11 9.14213e+00 8.00000e-11 8.06145e+00
+ 1.00000e-10 7.25464e+00 1.20000e-10 6.46398e+00 1.40000e-10
```

I have one file that generated some data from the tool(above data).
in the file where the line will start from + I need to filter data what I showed the expected output.

1st line data described as **time current time current time**
2st line data described as **current time current time current**
3rdst line data described as **time current time current time**
the same way all the lines continue.

I want to filter out 2 column time  column
time  column

I tried for almost half a day but had no luck someone please help on this

expected output is

```
time       column
0.00E+00    1.87E+00 
2.00E-11    1.09E+01 
4.00E-11    1.03E+01 
6.00E-11    9.14E+00 
8.00E-11    8.06E+00 
1.00E-10    7.25E+00 
1.20E-10    6.46E+00 
1.40E-10    next line data
```

Comment: @anubhava you can check now i missed some data

Comment: Could you explain in words, what you are trying to do?

Comment: @EdMorton I don't want to number conversion, I want they to be output in 2 columns,
only  I want numbers and other lines which are not started with ***+***

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub please check the description added

Comment: If you don't want number conversions then [edit] your question to show the same numbers in the output as you have in the input. Ditto for "next line data" - if you don;t want it in the output then don't show it in the output.

Comment: I see you've added column headers `time       column` to the expected output - do you REALLY want those? You're not printing them from your own code.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to simply show a sample input file and the exact output you expect given that input so we can help you.

Comment: Something like: `sed < inputFile 's/^+ //p;d' | xargs printf '%.2E\n'|xargs -n2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using any awk

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
/^\+/ {
    for ( i=2; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        printf "%0.2E%s", $i, (++c % 2 ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
END {
    if ( c % 2 ) {
        print "next line data"
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
0.00E+00        1.87E+00
2.00E-11        1.09E+01
4.00E-11        1.03E+01
6.00E-11        9.14E+00
8.00E-11        8.06E+00
1.00E-10        7.25E+00
1.20E-10        6.46E+00
1.40E-10        next line data
```

If you don't REALLY want "next line data" printed at the end of odd-number output then just change `print "next line data"` to `print ""` or remove the `END` section or do whatever else it is you really want to do in that situation.

Comment: thanks @EDMorton, is it possible to add other lines(not starting with +) to the file, where the above-mentioned data line starts with +

Comment: It's only software so sure, anythings possible. Ask a new question with it's own [mcve] as [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged on this forum.